# Using Nginx to remove part of a URL

Tags: nginx, rewrite

The url is http://www.mysite.com/CMS/roundabout/drive
and I need to remove the CMS portion and preserve the rest. I am stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Put the below line into the `server` context:

```
rewrite ^/CMS/(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 last;
```